# How to move Open edX from one machine to another

Tags: openedx

I am setting up Open edX to the wrong machine. I want to Open edX move to another machine. Can it possible? 
And Help needed to choose the right version of Open edX to install?

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible with the currently open-sourced set of scripts. You will have to do another installation on the target machine.

The right version of OpenEdx install depends on the kind of users you're planning to serve.

For a minimal, production-like installation, you could try the [native installation](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/146440579/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+16.04+64+bit+Installation)

For a quick testing, you could try the [devstack installation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/install_devstack.html)

For an even quicker devstack installation experience, you can give [tutor](https://docs.tutor.overhang.io/) a try

For a one-click installation without much dependence on the internet, you could try the [Bitnami installation](https://bitnami.com/stack/edx)

If you want to customize everything and install different components on different servers, you could refer to [this repo](https://github.com/dhasthagheer/edx-distributed-configuration) and move ahead from there.